# Difficulty in making wordpress site run which I migrated from Hostgator to DigitalOcean

Tags: wordpress, nginx, digital-ocean

I have tried every possible way to make the old wordpress site live on digitalocean, but couldn't succeed. Below is the nginx.config file, when I opened the current DigitalOcean IP address, getting blank page and also getting error in nginx/error/log index.php

2016/02/22 06:59:35 [error] 2282#0: *3 open() "/var/www/html/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 106.51.28.40, server: stockbucks.in, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "162.243.110.96", referrer: "http://162.243.110.96/"

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name stockbucks.in;

    location / {
    #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    location ~* ^.+.(css|js|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico|xml) {
            access_log off;
            expires 30d;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  }
```

Comment: Is the owner and grou of /var/www/html set correct? if not, please correct it (e.g. "chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html -R").
is php5-fpm installed and configured to accept connections via unix sockets?